# How can I update my Firestore with a HashMap using Hilt?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to update my UsersInfo in Firestore via HashMap in my Kotlin project with Hilt. I have the code to updated it but how do I do it with Hilt?

Below is my AppModule and the Repository where I'm already injecting a query.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideUserDetails(): DocumentReference =
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection(USERS)
            .document(getCurrentUserID())

    @Provides
    fun getCurrentUserID(): String {
        val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        var currentUserID = ""
        if (currentUser != null) {
            currentUserID = currentUser.uid
        }
        return currentUserID
    }

    @Provides
    fun getAllUsers(): Query =
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection(USERS)
            .whereNotEqualTo("id", getCurrentUserID())
}
```

```
@Singleton
class PlayersRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val queryProductsByName: DocumentReference
) {
    fun getPlayerFromFirestore(): DataOrException<Task<DocumentSnapshot>, Exception> {
        val dataOrException = DataOrException<Task<DocumentSnapshot>, Exception>()
        try {
            dataOrException.data = queryProductsByName.get()
        } catch (e: FirebaseFirestoreException) {
            dataOrException.e = e
        }
        return dataOrException
    }
suspend fun getAllPlayers() : DataOrException<List<Player>, Exception> {
            val dataOrException = DataOrException<List<Player>, Exception>()
            try {
                dataOrException.data = queryPlayers.get().await().map { document ->
                    document.toObject(Player::class.java)
                }
            } catch (e: FirebaseFirestoreException) {
                dataOrException.e = e
            }
            return dataOrException
}
}
```

and below is the method I'm trying to inject

```
    fun updateUserProfileData(fragment: ProfileFragment, userHashMap: HashMap<String, Any>) {
        firestore.collection(Constants.USERS)
            .document(getCurrentUserID())
            .update(userHashMap)
```

How do I inject it on the project?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. In one method you are getting a Task object from Firestore and in another, you are trying to write some data, without the use of any injected object. Besides that, don't use in your AppModule object that might be null.

Comment: I updated the code with a query I injected and it is working all right. But both methods on AppModule I use to retrieve data, I don't know how to write data in Firestore with dependencies injection

Comment: To understand better, so you want to inject the Query object that exists in the AppModle file into the PlayersRepository class, right?

Comment: I want to inject the updateUserProfileData that I have in a separate class to write data in Firestore

Comment: Injecting a method doesn't make any sense, can you clarify a bit?

Comment: When I'm using room, I inject a database and a Dao object that has read and write methods. I thought that with firebase would be the same. I should use the method to write data the same I was doing, without Hilt?

Comment: As @HenryTwist mentioned in his comment, there is no way you can inject a method. Only objects can be injected in activities/fragments. Please provide a clear explanation.

Comment: I don't know what I have to implement to wrtie data in Firestore using Hilt